# What are some appropriate & light PDF Viewers for Heavy PDFs?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, alongside Windows 7. I have some big and heavy pdf documents, nearly 70-80 MB. On some suggestions throughout the internet, I downloaded MuPDF. But MuPDF fails to open those heavy pdfs. Though the default Document-Viewer opens them, it is too heavy on processing and RAM. I opened same pdf in Windows7 using Foxit, and yes, it works less on processor and RAM too; so I didn't felt like going along with default document-viewer of Ubuntu.

So please suggest me a good PDF viewer, which can handle heavy pdfs and is  lighter on the system (processor, RAM).

Comment: I'm using MuPDF and it's great. I wonder why it fails… There is also xpdf, but it's not as good as MuPDF.

Comment: A note to reviewers: software recommendations are [on topic at AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14394/are-software-recommendations-on-topic-or-not). These questions are by nature broad, but in this case the requirements are rather objective.

Comment: mupdf  works great ... with plenty of RAM it handles a 140meg pdf no problem

Answer (score -1):

There's [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) (available from the Software Centre), but that might be too heavy for your needs.